# understanding factory design pattern

Tags: php, design-patterns

I was learning about factory design pattern in php. From what i understand, this pattern is useful in cases where we have a bunch of classes, lets say, **class_1, class_2, class_3** etc.
If the particular class which has to be instantiated is known only at runtime, then instead of using the new operator to create the objects for these classes we create a factory class which will do the job for us.

The factory class will look somewhat like this:

```
class Factory
{
// $type will have values 1, 2, 3 etc.
public function create_obj($type)
{
  $class_name = "class_".$type;
  if(class_exists($class_name))
  {
        return new $class_name();
  } 
}
}
```

My question is what is the advantage in using a factory **class** here? why not just use a **simple function** instead of a class which is going to complicate things?

Comment: That exists too and is called a FactoryMethod.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method in your code snippet is not a factory method, but merely a helper method which does a well-known [reflective](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_%28computer_programming%29) task: instantiates a class based on its name. This is exactly the opposite of what a [Factory pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) is for: *creating objects (products) **without specifying the exact class** of object that will be created*.

As explained in Wikipedia:

> The essence of this pattern is to *"Define an interface for creating an object, but let the classes that implement the interface decide which class to instantiate."*

You are probably confused by the last [PHP example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern#PHP_2) in the [Wikipedia article on Factory pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern), and yes, it is a bad example. Check the [Java example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern#Java_3) just above that for a meaningful example (whoever tried to convert that to PHP missed the whole point). The Java example returns a file reader based on its extension, and that is exactly the use case for a factory pattern. Creating your own personal "rule" that certain classes need to have a certain name prefix is most likely a bad design decision.

Answer (score 1):

At the basic root of the question you *could* use a simple function to accomplish the goal. Where this breaks down is the programmer best practice where you want Low Coupling, High Cohesion.

The function itself plays a special role in your application design and to put it alongside other functions with different roles and purposes is non-intuitive to maintain and read. Remember, patterns are used to simplify common problems that are faced (almost) universally through project domains and as a result they tend to be segmented from the rest of the code base in order to help differentiate them.

Additionally, by placing the pattern in its own class any classes that need to use it do not need to know the class structure of class_1/2/3/etc. and instead only need to refer to the parent class allowing you to create further classes down the line, modify the pattern accordingly without needing to resolve dependencies and links in your remaining code. This ties back to the low coupling.

Comment: i got your first point. but what you mean by "do not need to know the class structure of class_1/2/3/etc". Could you explain that in layman's terms?

Comment: I suppose it isn't much of a problem within PHP, but in other languages if you put the function within an existing class then you need to maintain a list of classes that the factory pattern would possibly need for each class that uses the factory pattern. In certain cases that would mean dozens of subclasses.

Answer (score 1):

The concept is that you design to an interface then you can swap out the class later.

Forget this pattern for a minute an consider this:

```
if (type == "manager")
    employee = new manager();
else
    employee = new employee();

employee.name = "myname";
```

In this case employee and manager both inherit from the same class.  After the if statement you can treat them like people and you are abstracted from their actual implementation.  Instead of having if statements all over the place, you can implement the factory pattern.  If you only have a couple the pattern is probably overkill.  If you want to easily extend the program in the future, consider a pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Another important reason for using the Factory Pattern is to consider what happens to your code when you have to **add classes to your design & code.**
If you're not using a Factory Pattern, your code is going to be increasingly **tightly coupled,** you'll have to make changes in many different places. You'll have to ensure that every place you have to touch the code is coordinated with all of the other (tightly coupled) places you'll have to touch.  **Testing becomes much, much more complicated,** and something is going to break.

The Factory Pattern gives you a way to reduce coupling and helps you to encapsulate responsibilities into just a few places. With a Factory Pattern, adding additional classes means touching the code in fewer places.  Testing  (constructing test cases as well as running tests) is simplified.

In the real world, most code is complex 'enough' that the benefits of the Factory Pattern are clear. Changing, refining and growing the object model, making testing as complete and rigorous as possible in the face of rapid change, and ensuring that you're making your code as non-rigid as possible (all while realizing that multiple people are going to be working on it over the course of months/years) -- the Factory Pattern is usually a no-brainer.

With a trivial example, it can be hard to see the advantages of using the Factory Pattern.  (And if your code really is trivial, then the pattern probably won't buy you much.)  That's a problem with many examples I see when I search for it on the web -- the examples tend to focus on 'you can determine the class at run-time!' and are simplistic.

Here's one example that's not too trivial, and I think gets people about thinking of all of the possible benefits of the pattern:
 [A presentation on the Factory Pattern by Bob Tarr (pdf)](http://userpages.umbc.edu/~tarr/dp/lectures/Factory.pdf). (It's example 2, starting about page 10.)  Imagine you're writing a maze game where a person has to explore a maze and all the rooms in a maze. Your object model include a **Maze** that consists of things like **Doors**, **Rooms**, **Walls**, and there's a **Map** that also has to keep track of them all. Simple enough.  But what happens when you start adding **Enchanted Rooms** and **Enchanted Doors** and **Magic Windows** and **Talking Pictures** and **Twisty Little Passages**?  You're going to end up with a lot of classes to represent everything; you want to make sure that you have to change (touch) as little code as possible when you add a new class.  And you don't want to have to modify the code in the **Map** class, for instance, each time you add a new class:  you want to keep the classes focused on what they should really be responsible for.

Think not just about what gets instantiated at run time, but also about code complexity.
He also gives an example of using the Factory Pattern (a Factory Method, specifically) with UI components -- where the Factory Pattern turns up a lot.  (For a beginner, or someone who has never dealt with UI code, I don't think that example is quite as clear.)

Remember that most coding is done on existing code: most time is spent modifying code that's already there.  You want to be sure that your code will be able to handle changes without being fragile.  Reducing coupling and encapsulating responsibility will go a long way in making it so.